# Paypal Returns Auth and nothing else as return data for a Subscription

Tags: .net, paypal, e-commerce, subscription

I am trying to set up a subscription payment for Paypal on .net. I am testing with the sandbox. When I submit the form to paypal and make the payment in the sandbox and then click on Return to Merchant, I get an auth variable containing some encrypted text. I expected query or form variables containing success or failure details.

Can anyone help me with this? I couldn't find any documentation, though I did find an unanswered question on a forum of a guy who had the same problem.

I am using the following code for the paypal form

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" 

id="paypaldata">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions"/> 
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="hidden_1319943901_biz@gmail.com"/> 
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Hidden Subscription"/> 
<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="27.00"/> 
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1"/> 
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M"/> 
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1"/> 
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
<input type="hidden" name="srt" value="0"/> 
<input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1"/> 
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="@ViewBag.Softid" />
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://localhost:5511/order/paypal" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, looks like I am destined to answer all my recent questions myself. I found the answer.

The reason was that I had IPN enabled on my Paypal account, and I had failed to include a notify_url in this code. When I included a notify_url, Paypal started sending me the transaction variables which had the details of the transaction.